# How to call models on javascript in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, model

I want to ask about my problem on javascript.

I want to make a confirmation message if there are values that have a same with databases, the confirm message show. If we click button OK, function on models will run, so the input will save.

Otherwise, if we click cancel, I want to back to before page or view. (it has solved by @Adam).

So, the problem is when I click button Ok or cancel the script to save or to run models still run. 
I think there is a mistake with call **$this->model_undangan->insert($data);** if write between javascript. It is like the program read php and then read javascript after that.

Maybe you can help me. Thank you for a help

this script like this

class Model_undangan extends CI_Model {

```
public function getinsert($data, $pembuka_acara, $waktu){
    $this->db->where('pembuka_acara', $pembuka_acara);
    $this->db->where('tanggal', $waktu);

    $query = $this->db->get('undangan');
    if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
        $row = $query->row();
            if(($row->pembuka_acara == 'Bupati') OR ($row->pembuka_acara == ' Wakil Bupati') OR ($row->pembuka_acara == 'Sekda')) {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";

                echo "if(confirm('Ada acara yang sama pada hari yang sama dengan pembuka acara ".$pembuka_acara.". Pilih lanjut untuk simpan, atau batal untuk ubah')){";
                echo "} else {";
                    echo "window.location.href='".site_url('undangan')."';
                } 
                </script>";

        } 
            $this->model_undangan->insert($data);
            echo "<script>";
            echo "alert('Undangan Berhasil Dikirim');
            window.location.href='".site_url('undangan')."';
            </script>";
    } else {
        $this->model_undangan->insert($data);
        echo "<script>";
            echo "alert('Undangan Berhasil Dikirim');
            window.location.href='".site_url('undangan')."';
            </script>";
    }


}


public function insert($data){
    $this->db->insert('undangan', $data);
        $id_undangan = $this->db->insert_id();

            foreach ($_POST['sopd_tujuan'] as $id_penerima) {
                $undangan['id_undangan'] = $id_undangan;
                $undangan['id_penerima'] = $id_penerima;
                $this->db->insert('detail_undangan', $undangan);
                return $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
            }

}
```

}

Comment: Please add your JS code snippet!

Comment: thanks @KarthickRamesh, I"ve added JS code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to back to before page or view, you can use "history.go(-1);"

Comment: thank you @Adam. it work for back to before page!

Comment: and now I still confused about how to write or call models when button ok was clicked

Comment: 1. getElement 
2. innerHTML
and I suggest you learn the document operation part of JavaScript, because my   English is not good, I don't know how to expression.

Comment: Thank you @Adam for your suggestion. I will learn like your suggestion for me. My english is bad too, so no problem if your english bad. I think the key of communication is you both understand

Answer (score 0):

you can try using an instance of CI

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$x=CI->functionName();
```

Note that to use "get_instance" u need to make sure that function name is already present in your previous controller from where the view has been loaded.

Comment: thank you before for your answer. I've tried like that your suggestion. But it still make the input always save on databases although I click on button cancel. Maybe it cause I write another language(php) ex: *x($data);* on javascript directly. Maybe you can give me another suggestion to fix that mistake.

Comment: Please try to use $('#id').click(function(){ call your instance here }); and validate to submit to the DB only when u press the correct button.

Comment: you were able to do that @maulidamaulida ?